# Some confusion regarding oAuth

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

I' am new to oAuth but I have read it's theory and I know about flow of different things in oAuth but I have a small confusion though.

I want to make my Windows App as a Consumer and my API Server a Provider in terms of oAuth. I' am using a library to make proper workflow of oAuth and my oAuth Server (API Server) returns **access_token** when user is authenticated and for each request to API Server that access_token is used to authenticate user. Now if I login with same account credentials on other machine then new access_token is not generated and already created access_token for that account is used. This thing have some issues because if I logout from one system then it gets logged-out from other system too.

I think that creation of same access_token for same authenticated account from two different machines is not related to oAuth in any way but I' am confused why that library used such a behavior. Is this behavior default to oAuth or is it just specific to that library? I just want to make sure that if I modify that library then I' am not violating oAuth default behavior.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.